# How to type the alif waslah on iPhone?

Tags: arabic, keyboard-layout

I have been using an Arabic keyboard on my iPhone for a while now, and one thing I can’t figure out how to type is the alif waslah.

For other markings above the ‘ا’ I hold down the key and I get options, but I do not see the alif waslah among them.

[image: image of iOS Arabic keyboard with the أ key held down]

I’ve tried finding the answer to this a couple times and for some reason been unable to do so. Any help is appreciated!

I don’t remember where I got the screenshot below but it is saved in my phone and may help explain what I’m trying to type:
[image: explanation of alif waslah]